# Batch script to delete .zip extension

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to delete `abc.zip` using a [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file).

I am using the below code to delete, but I am not able to delete a compressed zip folder, *normal folder is being deleted*.

```
@RD /S /Q  D:/test/test.zip
```

Could someone help me here?

Comment: `RD` is for removing directories, whereas you want to `DEL`ete a file. Open up a Command Prompt window and enter `RD /?` and `DEL /?` to read the usage information for each of those two commands, understand the difference, and modify your code accordingly.

Comment: You might be able to open and view a zip file like opening and viewing a folder in Explorer, but it is still a zip file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote this code.

`@RD /S /Q  D:/test/test.zip`

Replace this part `@RD /S /Q` with `del /f /q`

Full command: `del /f /q "D:/test/test.zip"`

RD stands for "Remove Directory" so natually it wont be used on files.